# How to remove the message Browser is under remote control from Firefox using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I want to remove this machine icon while running firefox using selenium using python3

[image: Firefox message]

Here is my code :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\\you\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\64nrwj2y.default-release')
PROXY_HOST = "87.255.27.163"
PROXY_PORT = "3128"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(PROXY_PORT))
profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
options=webdriver.firefox.options.Options()
profile.update_preferences()
desired = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
binary = FirefoxBinary('D:\\Mozilla Firefoxy\\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), desired_capabilities=desired)
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

But it keeps showing like this.

Answer (score -1):

As per the *Abstract* section of [WebDriver W3C Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) is a remote control interface that enables introspection and control of user agents. It provides a platform independent and language neutral wire protocol as a way for out-of-process programs to remotely instruct the behavior of web browsers.

WebDriver provides us a set of interfaces to discover and manipulate DOM elements in web documents and to control the behavior of a user agent. It is primarily intended to allow to write tests that automate a user agent from a separate controlling process and also be used in such a way as to allow in-browser scripts to control a separate browser.

Further, in the [Security](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#security) section of the specification also mentions that it was suggested that user agents make an effort to visually distinguish a user agent session that is under control of WebDriver from those used for normal browsing sessions. This can be done through a browser chrome element such as a **door hanger**, colorful decoration of the OS window, or some widget element that is prevalent in the window so that it easy to identify automation windows.

This feature is implemented in [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) through the *Robot* icon along with the *tool tip* which reads *`"Browser is under remote control"`*

[image: Browser is under remote control]